# How to update value of row in table in sqlite phonegap

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Want to update  data of row in table.

I have the ID of table,to which I need to set another value.

I have text field, I need to add / update value which is written in text field.

I am using upgap sqlite .

Comment: i am using this.. tx.executeSql('UPDATE CaseTable SET CaseName ="'+$('#documentCaseName').val()+'"+ WHERE id = ' + ROW_ID);

Comment: and what u have as response?

Comment: Put an answer and mark it as solved.It can help somebody else someday

Answer (score 1):

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE CaseTable SET CaseName = "' + caseName + '",CaseDate = "' + caseDate + '",TextArea = "' + caseTextArea + '" WHERE id = ' + ROW_ID);
```